# Шрифты helvetica

Tags: css

Мне нужно вставить  2 шрифта helvetica lt std cond, helvetica lt std bold cond . На бреакпоинте @media (max-width: 767.98px) он становится helvetica lt std bold cond.
Всё бы ничего только вот всё что я скачиваю и пытаюсь установить тупо не работает. Может ли кто подсказать откуда скачать рабочие файлы и как их установить?

```css
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica lt std cond';
    src: url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Light.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'helvetica lt std bold cond';
        src: url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-LightCond.eot');
        src: url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-LightCond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-LightCond.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/fonts/HelveticaLTStd-LightCond.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        }
```

Comment: Можно целый код, а не часть? Хотябы css

Comment: Если вас интересует подключение .logo-text{ font-family: 'helvetica lt std cond', sans-serif;}

Comment: Вот самый крутой сайт шрифтов, скачиваете, как в примере устанавливаете и пользуетесь - https://webfonts.pro/base-web-fonts/sans-serif-grotesque/504-helvetica-lt.html